# jQuery hide + CSS hover issue with mouse

Tags: jquery, css, hover, refresh, mouse

Has anyone else noticed that when you have the CSS:hover effect applied to an element, hide that element and keep the mouse perfectly still, the hover effect is still present until the mouse moves?

I've has a search but can't seem to find any other threads similar. I know it is probably easy but I cannot find the solution and it will cause me to end up in Bedlam.

To see what I mean, take a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NsMKN/ and

1. Click the black box to expand it
2. move the cursor outside the original blackness like where the red X is
3. click to hide and keep the mouse cursor PERFECTLY still
4. notice the black box is still red???

When the cursor moves, the :hover is not applied as it should, but it there a way to do this without having to move the mouse and without having to apply the hover effect using jQuery myself (leaving it to CSS)?

**Update:** I've marked Starx as the answer as it does appear to be an IE thing. Thanks for the help guys.

[image: awesome piccy]

Comment: I'm not seeing this on Chrome 21.0.1180.15 dev, Safari 5.1.7 or Firefox 12.0, all on OS X. It does happen on IE9, though.

Comment: `:)` not clear what you need but - if you dont wanna apply jquery css effect then how JQuery is tagged in this question but see if this suffice you needs :) http://jsfiddle.net/2C9vh/ hope it helps

Comment: Not seeing on FireFox 13 either But yes it can be seen on IE 8

Comment: @Tats_innit I think the question is asking us not to keep the box red.

Comment: @AdityaSaxena Thanks man! hmm lol then it works as it supposed to :) tested in < Chrome >

Comment: @Tats_innit yep! it actually works like it should. Maybe it's not working in some other browsers.

Comment: @AdityaSaxena lol okies, by the way I have not given you any negative rating - just to be clear `:))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me split your code.

```
<div class="tester">
    <div class="content">
        apple, banana, carrot, lettuce, celery, beetroot
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, the div `.content` is inside `.tester` which wraps itself with respect to the what is inside, on general cases.

```
.tester:hover
{
   background-color:red; 
}
```

Your CSS is also applied to the same wrapper div i.e. `.tester`. So, that when the mouse is over to this part, its background color will change.

```
$('.tester').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.content').toggle();
});
```

Now, when you toggle the inner element to make it visible. The dimensions of the `.tester` will change according to the inner elements. Although it is fixed in your case, DOM also has to consider its children. Try to do the same with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NsMKN/3/).

[image: Example Showing the Issue]

Due to this reason The **the mouse will still** be over the div `.tester`. So, style of `.tester:hover` will still be applied.

Now, when you the toggle `.content`, the wrapper div `.tester` will retain the previous state, until further event occurs.

Browsers like IE, does not seem to update its DOM properties until *next event occurs*.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is not occurring for me.
However, you could try this :
http://jsfiddle.net/NsMKN/1/

```
.tester
{
   width:100px;
   min-height:100px;
   background-color:Black;
}
```

Comment: Okay i am not sure why the negative rating:) But what I'm trying to do here is set the min-height of the container to be 100px.

This way, 100px height does not interfere with the content's 500px height. Cheers to whoever gave the negative rating, though!

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but the question seems to be about browser issues, rather than coding fault.